# unable to start zookeeper on CentOS 7

Tags: java, centos, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

When I try to start the Zookeeper server, I got the error

> bash: zkServer.sh: command not found...

I had followed the installation instruction given in the [Solr 7.5 documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html)

And in the zoo.cfg file I had added the below information.

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181

initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=192.168.8.10:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.8.11:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.8.12:2888:3888

autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

I have CentOS 7 and I have installed Java version 1.8.0_191 and I have set the Environment Variable by editing .bash_profile file with the following.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_191
export PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_191/bin:$PATH
```

I had tried with **zkServer.sh start** command and **zkServer.sh start-foreground**
Both commands are not working. Can any one give suggestion to solve this issue.

[image: Zookeeper Start Error]

Comment: The error message is that the command is not found. You might try `./zkServer.sh start`, which would invoke the command in the current directory, which appears to be `zookeeper-3.4.13/bin`.

Comment: @KevinO Thank you so much Kevin. It's working...